# WF Workflow Service Error Cannot obtain Metadata from http://localhost/OrderService/Service1.xamlx

Tags: workflow

I have created a Workflow service using Microsoft WF (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff432975%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

When i run the service in visual studio I'm getting the below error

```
Error: Cannot obtain Metadata from http://localhost/OrderService/Service1.xamlx
```

If this is a Windows (R) Communication Foundation service to which you have access, please check that you have enabled metadata publishing at the specified address.
For help enabling metadata publishing, please refer to the MSDN documentation at http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=65455.WS-Metadata Exchange Error    URI: http://localhost/OrderService/Service1.xamlx 
Metadata contains a reference that cannot be resolved: 'http://localhost/OrderService/Service1.xamlx'.
The server did not provide a meaningful reply; this might be caused by a contract mismatch, a premature session shutdown or an internal server error.HTTP GET Error    URI: http://localhost/OrderService/Service1.xamlx 
There was an error downloading 'http://localhost/OrderService/Service1.xamlx'.    The request failed with an empty response.

My config is below. I have added the Meta Exchange lines in the config file also.

```
<system.serviceModel>
<services>
  <service behaviorConfiguration="metadataBehavior" name="MyService">
    <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
  </service>
</services>
<behaviors>      
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior  name="metadataBehavior">
      <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the values below to false before deployment -->
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
      <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
      <!--Connection String for the WF SQL Presistance-->
      <sqlWorkflowInstanceStore connectionString="Data Source=AAAAA;Initial Catalog=KK_SQLPersistenceStore;Asynchronous Processing=True" instanceEncodingOption="None" instanceCompletionAction="DeleteAll" instanceLockedExceptionAction="BasicRetry" hostLockRenewalPeriod="00:00:30" runnableInstancesDetectionPeriod="00:00:02" />
      <workflowIdle timeToUnload="0"/>
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try changing you endpoint address to this
`<endpoint address="http://localhost/OrderService/Service1.xamlx/mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />`